# Add all Keys to an array then iterate?

Tags: c#, key

So I want to be able to add all Keys to an Array of Keys, so that I can easily iterate over them and manipulate them.

So I would want something like this:

A bit of pseudo code.

```
Keys[] keys = ..All the keys..;
for(int i = 0; i<keys.Length; i++) {
   //do something with the key here.
}
```

Basically what I want is to add all Keys from the Object 'Keys' (It's a default Object, not my own) into an array of Keys[] so that I can iterate through those keys one by one.

http://puu.sh/uhLI

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question considerably before anyone will be able to answer it. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: `for` is one of the most basic control structures which is learned on the second programming lesson. What could be simpler?

Comment: The Doing part is not really what I need, I just need a way to have all the Keys in an array.

Comment: What is this data type `Keys`? Is it something of your own, or coming from a library (e.g. ADO.NET)? Where are the keys coming from?

Comment: What kind of instance is `..All the keys..`?

Comment: How does one determine "all keys"?  And if you have an easy way to doi that, why do you need the array?

Comment: Updated post, should give more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that you want to turn the enumeration `System.Windows.Input.Key` into an array, then you can do this:

```
Key[] keys = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key)).Cast<Key>().ToArray();
```

and of course you could obtain an `IEnumerable<Key>` as

```
IEnumerable<Key> keys = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key)).Cast<Key>();
```

If you mean that you want to turn the enumeration `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` into an array then the same code applies

```
Keys[] keys = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)).Cast<Keys>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Is System.Windows.Input.Key an default library? It can't seem to reference or import it.

Comment: @DuncanPalmer it's in WindowsBase.dll - probably WPF specific.